# Running sfdx force:apex:execute result in error

Tags: apex, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to run the below script on my sandbox-

```
sfdx force:apex:execute -u SandboxName -f fileName.apex.cls
```

and I get this error -
**Error: Line: 1, Column: 5
Error: Unexpected token '<'.**

File Contents -

```
List<CustomObject__c> orders = [SELECT Id, Name, field__c, temp_field__c FROM CustomObject__c WHERE field__c !='' AND CreatedDate >= 2023-01-16 LIMIT 1];
for (CustomObject__c order : orders) {
    order.temp_field__c = order.field__c;
}
update orders;
System.debug('Updated '+orders.size()+' record(s) ');
```

Comment: What's the contents of your file?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I have added the file contents to my post.

Comment: The compiler is giving you fits because the query isn't valid or you're missing a semi-colon somewhere in your code. `CreatedDate` must be filtered with `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format, for example.

Comment: @sfdxfox, thanks for chiming in. I figured it out, it was a double AND operator on my script.

Comment: Yeah, no problem!